# Please explain me this code if (input >= '0' && input <= '9')

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    char input;
    printf("Please enter a character: ");
    scanf("%c", &input);
    if (input >= '0' && input <= '9')
        printf("DIGIT\n");
    else
        printf("NOT DIGIT\n");
    getch();
}
```

The line contains relational operator with char data type, what's going here?
`if (input >= '0' && input <= '9')`

Comment: The C specification requires that all digit characters are encoded contiguously. Meaning that the value for `'0'` is less than the value for `'1'` etc. up to `'9'` which will have the highest value. That means you can check if a character is a digit by making sure that it's in the range of `'0'` to `'9'`.

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: As how it's possible to compare two characters, it's because in C, despite the `char` type, all characters are converted to `int` values. What's happening with the comparison `intput >= '0'` is that the `int` value of the character in `input` is compared to the `int` value of `'0'` (which is `48` in the ASCII encoding scheme).

Comment: And lastly, that condition should really have been using [the standard character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification). As in `if (isdigit(input))`.

Comment: I can understand a little bit, please explain me a little more, shall be thankful to you

Comment: @mr.neeo Explain more? What's unclear?

Comment: Its looking illogical that '0' and '9' can detect all digits